# How to fix this table when exporting to excel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, excel

I use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) to display my data as a table. It has several button on the top of the header. One button may export the data into excel. However, the exported data is failed to open in excel because the error of `unreadable content`.

After some debug, I found that this is caused from this
`<input type="hidden" class="note_dr_dh" value="<?php echo $row->DISPOSISI; ?>" />`

I also have several hidden textboxes, but only that particular hidden textbox is the source of my problem. When I export it to CSV, I found that the text in the hidden textbox is also exported to excel while the other textboxes values are not. It's used for some features in my app, so it should not be removed.

my export script:

```
$('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
    pageLength  : 10,
    responsive  : true,
    dom         : '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    buttons     : [
                    {extend: 'copy'},
                    {extend: 'csv', title: "Daftar_Seluruh_Surat_<?php echo $this->session->userdata('dept'); ?>"},
                    {extend: 'excel', title: "Daftar_Seluruh_Surat_<?php echo $this->session->userdata('dept'); ?>"},
                    {extend: 'pdf', title: "Daftar_Seluruh_Surat_<?php echo $this->session->userdata('dept'); ?>"},
                    {extend: 'print',
                        customize: function (win){
                            $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                            $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                            $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('compact').css('font-size', 'inherit');
                        }
                    }
    ]
});
```

My table (not all column. Only the one with the problem):

```
<td class="text-center td_link" style="vertical-align:middle !important">
   <a style="text-decoration:none" class='a_surat' href='javascript:void(0)'><?php echo $row->ID_REQUIREMENT; ?></a>
   <input type="hidden" class="id_req" value="<?php echo $row->ID_REQUIREMENT; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" class="note_dr_dh" value="<?php echo $row->DISPOSISI; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" class="uploaded" value="<?php echo $row->UPLOAD_IMAGE; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" class="stat_memo" value="<?php echo $row->STATUS; ?>" />
</td>
```

Note (if these help):

- `$row->ID_REQUIREMENT, $row->UPLOAD_IMAGE, $row->STATUS, $row->UPLOAD_IMAGE` = VARCHAR
- `$row->DISPOSISI` = TEXT;

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a hidden span after the hidden textboxes :
`<input type="hidden" class="note_dr_dh" value="<?php echo $row->DISPOSISI; ?>" /><span style="display: none;"></span>`

or

add this on your datatable script :

```
$('.dataTables-example').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
       {
           extend: 'excel',
           title: "Daftar_Seluruh_Surat_<?php echo $this->session->userdata('dept'); ?>",
           exportOptions: {
               stripHtml: false // to enable the element styling
           }               
       }        
    ]      
} );
```

Comment: The error is gone. But, the text inside the hidden textbox is also exported. How to avoid this?

Comment: What if adding hidden style on your textbox like this : `<input type="hidden" class="note_dr_dh" value="<?php echo $row->DISPOSISI; ?>" style="display: none;" />`